# Different definitions of projective morphisms of schemes.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I encountered three different definitions about a projective morphism $X\to S$, with $S$ a noetherian scheme.

The first one is from Grothendieck: the morphism is projective if there exists a coherent sheaf $E$ on $S$, together with an closed embedding of $X$ into $\mathbb{P}(E)$ over $S$.

The second one is called strongly projective: the morphism is strongly projective if there exists a vector bundle $E$ on $S$ together with a closed embedding $X\to \mathbb{P}(E)=\operatorname{Proj} (\operatorname{Sym}_{\mathcal{O}_S}E)$ over $S$.

The third one is from Hartshorne’s, which is also the strongest form: the morphism is projective if $X$ admits a closed embedding into $\mathbb{P}^n_S$ for some $n$.

Then it’s said that, in general, these three definitions are distinct. And some conditions for equivalence are given:

1. If the morphism is projective and flat, then it’s strongly projective. Also, if every coherent sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_S-$ modules  is a quotient of a vector bundle, then projectivity is equivalent to strong projectivity.
2. If $S$ admits an ample line bundle, then all three definitions are equivalent to each other.

My questions are as follows:

1. Why can’t every coherent sheaf of module be written as quotient of a vector bundle? Since on some open neighborhood $U$, we could get a exact sequence $R|_{U} \to \oplus _r \mathcal{O}_S|_{U}\to E\to 0$ for some integer $r$ by the definition of coherent module.
2. I guess flatness in condition 1 is to make sure for some open
   neighborhood $U$, $X|_U$ looks like $\mathbb{P}(V)$ for some vector
   bundle $V$ because flatness means locally free under some finiteness
   conditions. If $X$ is noetherian, we could choose a vector bundle $W$
   with dimension bigger enough that $X$ admits a closed embedding into
   $\mathbb{P} (W)$. If not how can we complete the proof?
3. Given a vector bundle $V$ with dimension $r$, what’s the difference between $\mathbb{P}^r_S$ and $\mathbb{P}(V)$? In condition 2, admitting an ample line bundle means sections can be extended to global sections after some twisting. So the difference is the structure sheaf $\mathbb{P}(V)$ may not be generated by global sections, right?

Finally, in Hartshorne’s, the definition of a very ample invertible sheaf is slightly different from that in EGA. Could anyone provide the definition in EGA? Thank in advance!

Comment: You are aware that EGA is [available on the internet](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~leila.schneps/grothendieckcircle/pubtexts.php) and you can look yourself, right?

Comment: The defintion of very ample in EGA is this one https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01VL.

Comment: 1) Every coherent sheaf can locally be written as the quotient of a vector bundle (which is what you explained), but this not imply the corresponding global statement.

Comment: Also, I recommend Chapter 17 of http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGnov1817public.pdf